# Export vectors from Illustrator and trim out extra canvas to use in Latex

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, export, save, latex

Is there a way to save an Illustrator file as `pdf` without the canvas? Somehow, when I save as `pdf` I always end up having the "whole" canvas saved with it. In contrary, when I export to, lets say `png`, I only get the actual drawn object.

Is there a possibility to save as `pdf`, because it will be a vector graphic instead of pixel, with only drawn object?

Comment: Not that I am aware of but how are you reusing the PDF afterwards? If you are importing it in InDesign, you can easily remove the canvas.

Comment: I want to use the figure in LaTeX, therefore would prefer vector graphics.

Comment: Can't LaTeX import EPSes? If you want a vector image, why would you export as PDF?

Comment: I felt that the old title was misleading. I left the pdf part there, but all and all I did feel like this was just about trimming the white space and nothing to do with pdf specifically. Feel free to change it back if you think the new title is not fitting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably, you would like this way

click on menu item <kbd>Object</kbd>-><kbd>Artboards</kbd>-><kbd>Fit to Artwork Bounds</kbd> and after that <kbd>File</kbd>-><kbd>Save As</kbd>... PDF as usual.

If you want artboard size back - just press <kbd>Command-Z</kbd> or if you on Win <kbd>Control-Z</kbd> after saving.

---

The same result you can achieve by pressing <kbd>Shift-O</kbd> (or clicking on the artboard icon) and choosing the option as on the picture -

[image]

Comment: Nice! Didn't know of the artboard tool.